# Identify and Remove Frame Busting Code?

Tags: javascript, iframe, facebook-iframe

I was experiencing a bug with my Facebook 'like' buttons.  The fix for the bug was posted here:

http://wiki.github.com/facebook/connect-js/custom-channel-url

At the beginning of this solution it states that the bug only occurs on pages with autostart video (which I don't have) or pages with frame busting code.

I'm therefore assuming my site (http://twistedtime.com) has frame busting code.  I'm using a cms so not sure what this code is or what I should look for so I can remove it.

Does anyone know what the frame busting code would look like?

Comment: knowing which cms you're using would be very helpful.

Comment: The store is running on Magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good examples of such code on Wikipedia: [Frame Killer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)

From the homepage of the web site you refer to I did a simple search through all the Javascript for `window.top` and it didn't return anything that looked like it was killing frames.

I *think* the problem lies elsewhere.